# Multiplying bytes with XOR

Tags: c++, aes

So, before I get into my question. I tried search this but I am probably not wording it correctly to get any valid results. So the purpose is to use in the a AES 128-bit encryption program.

I need to multiply an unsigned char (which would be the hexadecimal value) by 2 or 3 and this would be an `XOR` operation. So basically, is there a way to do it without typing it out like this.

```
(SBOX[0] ^ SBOX[0]) ^ SBOX[0]
```

If I have to do it this way, each line is going to be fairly long but can be done I believe. It would be nice if there is an operator to just say `3 ^ SBOX[0]`.

Comment: `(x ^ x) ^ x == x ^ (x ^ x) == x`, so... what is the point of XORing the same value thrice?

Comment: Triple XOR encryption is utterly uncrackable!

Comment: If you want to  multiply why not `3 * SBOX[0]`?

Comment: When you say "multiply" do you mean as in mathematically? If so XOR is not part of the solution here. Also, multiplying by 2 is a bitshift operation, but by 3 is a lot more involved. Like `n*3` is also `(n<<1)+n` but that's really way more work than just multiplying.

Comment: @tadman uncrackable... That's what they said about Double ROT13.

Comment: @tadman - Re: "XOR is not part of the solution" - It is if you're implementing Galois Field arithmetic (which is likely what's being used here).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's probably the case, but what's here is a request to multiply by "2 or 3".

Comment: Another thing to note is that "hexadecimal" is just a *representation* of a number, not how the number's stored. Computers encode things differently than they're presented on screen as a series of pixels or letters. An `unsigned char` is a very specific representation.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold).

Comment: Sorry, my question isn't that clear. Basically I want to know if there is a better way of writing the code, rather than writing it out completely. here is an actual example. temp[0] = (state[0] ^ state[0]) ^ ((state[1] ^ state[1]) ^ state[1]) ^ state[2] ^ state[3];

Comment: @tadman - Multiplication *in GF(2^8)* though.  What the OP has is wrong, but it's also not as simple as `* 2` (or `* 3`).  (I think what they need is something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns#Implementation_example).)

Comment: `x ^ x == 0`, so we still kind of have no idea what do you want...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You are correct. That is the goal, except in C++. Thanks, that page will come in useful.

Comment: The question is pretty clear if you're familiar with the subject - thus I've voted to re-open.

Comment: @Fureeish "`x ^ x == 0`" I defy anyone to decrypt _that_

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing AES, then you're doing your arithmetic in a [Galois Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) (specifically GF(2<sup>8</sup>)).  Thus rules that you're used to for standard integers no longer hold.

In particular, whilst addition *is* XOR (in GF(2<sup>n</sup>)), multiplication isn't repeated addition.  Your example shows why - multiplication by two would be `x ^ x == 0` always.

The actual steps (in code) depend on the reducing polynomial of your Galois field (and in any case, deriving them is way beyond my ability nowadays).  However, they're summarised in multiple places on the web.  And in many case, these explanations specifically target the S-box MixColumns operation, e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns#Implementation_example).

Comment: Thanks for the information. You saved me a lot of headache.